# Mobile version of the page not showing

Tags: 2013, mobile

I am trying to test the mobile version of a site.  Mobile Browser View feature in enable and other sites in the collection appear OK on a mobile device.

The error I get is.....

Pages: home

(Some apps, such as Content Editor, are not supported in mobile view. Tapping on title area can bring up navigation window.)

Also on another site I get the desktop version with no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can disable the Mobile Browser view feature for that site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mobile adapter so that with the mobile view activated you can still render all the webpart.
Ref. below link : 
http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2010/01/17/sharepoint-2010-mobile-web-part-development/